# Problemas com DRAG e DROP utilizando Redpis

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, redips.drag

Tenho uma aplicação que gera um gridView (ASP.NET) de informações e em cada coluna eu posso possuir 2 valores. Um desses valores é o tempo total de trabalho (x) de uma pessoa para uma data especifica, e o outro valor é o tempo de trabalho (y) já planejado para a pessoa. O tempo Y pode ser arrastado para qualquer outra coluna de X, porém ao efetuar a alteração, eu necessito realizar uma conta de subtração (x-y), ai que está o problema.

Consegui definir um evento "event.dropped", do Redips, que sempre ao DROPPAR uma div em uma td ele envia um alert("teste"):

```
redipsInit = function () {

var rd = REDIPS.drag,
    msg = document.getElementById('message');

rd.style.borderDisabled = 'solid';  
rd.style.opacityDisabled = 60;      
rd.init();

    rd.event.dropped = function () {
    var teste = 'Dropped';
    alert(teste);
    };
};
```

Eu preciso de alguma forma capturar o valor da td onde a DIV foi droppada, pois la vou conseguir capturar as duas DIVS, tanto a já existente (X), quanto a droppada (Y), fazer os calculos e substituir os valores.

Alguem sabe alguma solução? Não necessáriamente necessito de uma solução Redips, pois estou utilizando tudo isso junto ao .NET, então uma solução .NET também ajudaria. Vlw.

Comment: Você quer pegar o valor do td, e não o id do elemento que você esta incluindo nê?

Comment: exatamente, pois o td contém o valor das duas DIV X e Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei algo que resolve!! Agora eu tenho as referencias de coluna, antes da modificação e depois da modificação, o que me da a possibilidade de realizar a leitura do grid e obter os valores posteriormente.

```
var redipsInit;
var colClick01;
var colClick02;
var colDrop01;
var colDrop02;

redipsInit = function () {

rd.init();

rd.event.clicked = function () {
    var pos = rd.getPosition();
    colClick01 = pos[1];
    colClick02 = pos[2];
};

rd.event.dropped = function () {
    var pos = rd.getPosition();
    colDrop01 = pos[1];
    colDrop02 = pos[2];
    alert('Antes - linha =' + colClick01 + ', coluna =' + colClick02 + ' -- Depois - linha =' + colDrop01 + ', coluna =' + colDrop02);
};
```